# access Oracle VM virtualmachine's database from local computer in Visual Studio c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, oracle

How to access Oracle  virtual machines database from the local computer in Visual Studio  C# .NET?

I have tried following

```
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();

con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION="
    + "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.15)(PORT=1521))"
    + "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL)));"
    + "User Id=oracle;Password=oracle;";
```

using the above code I am not able to connect to VMware Oracle database
getting an exception

> An exception of type 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException'
>   occurred in Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll but was not handled in user
>   code

Comment: What is the message of exception?

Comment: Since it is on a virtual machine, have you checked whether all your ports are accessible and open for connection? You may have to do some port-forwarding.

Comment: External component has thrown an exception.

Comment: Better to include exception details and stack trace, because "external component" may related to unmanaged code or something else. Also check the connection availability to the VM.

Comment: how I can check port access enable or not  in my VM @priyank Panchal

Comment: Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: Connection request timed out

Comment: @MangeshUkade though a Network profiler can help understand whether port is open, but you can simply ping machine and if that's successful, then try connecting via SqlClient as I have described, which will help understand if machine is up but network port is blocked